# Consider $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x)=4x$. Is there any homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h\circ f=g\circ h$

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Consider $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x)=4x$. Is there any homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h\circ f=g\circ h$?
Well it means $h(2x)=4h(x)$ but I don't know what to do from here?

Comment: you meant homEomorphism?

Comment: @AnatoliyR Typo. Yes.

Comment: Did you intend $h \circ f = g \circ h$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes! my bad!

Comment: In this case, I think you can show that $h(2^n) = 4^n h(1)$ and $h(0)=0$ fairly quickly.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Well  $h(0)=0$ is obvious but how about $h(2^n)=4^{n}h(1)$? Does that help at all?

Comment: $h(2) = 4 h(1)$ and so on. It might help.. Not certain yet. I'm still piecing out together. Similarly, $h(-2^n)=4^n h(-1)$. Likewise, $h(2^{-n}) = 4^{-n} h(1)$ and cc for negatives.

Comment: How about $h(x) = x^2$ for $x>0$ and $h(x) = -x^2$ for $x<0$ ? Does that work?

Comment: @Ned Well it seems to work. How did you come up with such $h$?

Comment: well, let $a=h(1)$, then $h(2) = 4a$, $h(4) = 16a$, etc ... it just suggested trying $h(x) = x^2$ 

Comment: @Ned make that an answer! I'm trying to math from bed and clearly missing the forest for the trees so I think I need to turn in..

Comment: @EricTowers I asked that question at the same time and got different insights from solutions suggested for both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h(x) = x^2$ for $x>0$ and $h(x) = -x^2$ for $x<0$ seems to work.

Comment: Thanks Ned. I wait for other possible approaches if it did not happen I will accept it as an answer.